# How to receive output of a started PHP.EXE with -S parameter?

Tags: c#, php, .net, command-line-interface

I'm using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809005/107625) to start PHP.EXE from a C# application:

```
var start =
    new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\PHP\v7.0\php.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp",
        Arguments = "…some arguments…",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    };

using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = start;

    p.OutputDataReceived += (o, args) => log(args.Data);
    p.ErrorDataReceived += (o, args) => log(args.Data);

    p.Start();

    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();

    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

This works perfectly when starting the PHP.EXE console application for a single file ([the `-f` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)):

Whenever the child process console application writes something to STDOUT, my application immediately receives it through the event.

Just as expected.

However, my C# program does *not* receive any output when calling PHP.EXE with [the `-S` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) (i.e. running with the **built-in web server**).

Doing the same manually on the command line, I do get an output, similar to this one:

```
C:\>"C:\PHP\v7.0\php.exe" -S localhost:21919 -t "C:\some\folder"
PHP 7.0.9 Development Server started at Fri Oct 14 00:46:16 2016
Listening on http://localhost:21919
Document root is C:\some\folder
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Fri Oct 14 00:46:17 2016] ::1:26671 [200]: /
[Fri Oct 14 00:46:17 2016] ::1:26673 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Fri Oct 14 00:46:21 2016] ::1:26675 [200]: /
[Fri Oct 14 00:46:21 2016] ::1:26676 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

This seems to be not receivable through my `Process.Start` call.

I guess that it is related due how PHP runs its built-in web server.

**My question:**

Is there any chance to still capture the output, even if PHP.EXE is called with the `-S` parameter?