# log text from a console-application to a richtextbox in another project

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, console, console-application

I've made a console application and a windowsforms application. They both work together and i wonder if there's a way to log the console application output to a richtextbox in the other project?

Comment: Code samples? More details?

Comment: The answer is: yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way.  You run the console app from within the forms app and put the output into the text box.

The Process class has methods to start the console app and grab its output, then you stuff that output into the text box.  There are plenty of details for you to look over but it's pretty straightforward.

More info here: [Get Live output from Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808663/get-live-output-from-process)