# handle error from external console application in powershell script

Tags: powershell

my powershell script calls a third party console application which uses custom commands. I want powershell to try to run that console applications command but if an error is returned (not by the powershell script but the external console app) which contains a specific string then run another command instead. If not just move onto the next instruction in the script.

What would be the best way of handling that, so basically:

if command1 returns "error1" then run command2. if command 1 does not return error1 skip command2 and move down the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can call and catch errors of native applications in many ways.
Some examples:

### 1. `Most easy` with no process handling, no distinguishing between success and error.

```powershell
$nativeAppFilePath = 'ping.exe'

# parameters as collection. Parameter-Value pairs with a space in between must be splitted into two.
$nativeAppParam= @(
    'google.com'
    '-n'
    '5'
)

# using powershell's call operator '&' 
$response = & $nativeAppFilePath $nativeAppParam
$response
```

### 2. `Easy`, same as 1., but distinguishing between success and error possible.

```powershell
$nativeAppFilePath = 'ping.exe'

 # parameters as collection. Parameter-Value pairs with a space in between must be splitted into two.
$nativeAppParam= @(
    'google2.com'
    '-n'
    '5'
)
 
# using powershell's call operator '&' and redirect the error stream to success stream
$nativeCmdResult = & $nativeAppFilePath $nativeAppParam 2>&1

if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    # success handling
    $nativeCmdResult

} else {
    # error handling
    #   even with redirecting the error stream to the success stream (above)..
    #   $LASTEXITCODE determines what happend if returned as not "0" (depends on application)
    Write-Error -Message "$LASTEXITCODE - $nativeCmdResult"
}
```

> ### ! Now two more complex snippets, which doesn't work with "ping.exe" (but most other applications), because "ping" doesn't raise error events.

### 3. `More complex` with process handling, but still process blocking until the application has been finished.

```
$nativeAppProcessStartInfo = @{
    FileName               = 'ping.exe' # either OS well-known as short name or full path
    Arguments              = @(
        'google.com'
        '-n 5'
    )
    RedirectStandardOutput = $true  # required to catch stdOut stream 
    RedirectStandardError  = $true  # required to catch stdErr stream 
    UseShellExecute        = $false # required to redirect streams
    CreateNoWindow         = $true  # does what is says (background work only)
}

try {
    $nativeApp= [System.Diagnostics.Process]@{
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
        StartInfo           = $nativeAppProcessStartInfo
    }
    
    [void]$nativeApp.Start()

    # Warning: As soon as the buffer gets full, the application could stuck in a deadlock. Then you require async reading
    #   see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608823/13699968
    $stdOut = $nativeApp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stdErr = $nativeApp.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    # To avoid deadlocks with synchronous read, always read the output stream first and then wait. 
    #   see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks
    $nativeApp.WaitForExit()

    if ($stdOut.Result) {
        # success handling
        $stdOut.Result
    }

    if ($stdErr.Result) {
        # error handling
        $stdErr.Result
    }

} finally {
    $nativeApp.Dispose()
}
```

### 4. `The most complex` with realtime output & reaction, capturing, and so on...

This time with wmic.exe and a nonsense parameter as example.

```powershell
$appFilePath  = 'wmic.exe'
$appArguments = @(
    'someNonExistentArgument'
)
$appWorkingDirPath = ''

# handler for events of process
$eventScriptBlock = {
    # $Event is an automatic variable. Only existent in scriptblocks used with Register-ObjectEvent
    # received app output
    $receivedAppData = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Data

    # Write output as stream to console in real-time (without -stream parameter output will produce blank lines!)
    #   (without "Out-String" output with multiple lines at once would be displayed as tab delimited line!)
    Write-Host ($receivedAppData | Out-String -Stream)

    <#
        Insert additional real-time processing steps here.
        Since it is in a different scope, variables changed in this scope will not get changed in parent scope 
        and scope "$script:" will not work as well. (scope "$global:" would work but should be avoided!)
        Modify/Enhance variables "*MessageData" (see below) before registering the event to modify such variables.
    #>

    # add received data to stringbuilder definded in $stdOutEventMessageData and $stdErrEventMessageData
    $Event.MessageData.Data.AppendLine($receivedAppData)
}


# MessageData parameters for events of success stream
$stdOutEventMessageData = @{
    # useful for further usage after application has been exited
    Data = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

    # add additional properties necessary in event handler scriptblock above
}


# MessageData parameters for events of error stream
$stdErrEventMessageData = @{
    # useful for further usage after application has been exited
    Data = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

    # add additional properties necessary in event handler scriptblock above
}


#######################################################
#region Process-Definition, -Start and Event-Subscriptions
#------------------------------------------------------
try {
    $appProcessStartInfo = @{
        FileName               = $appFilePath
        Arguments              = $appArguments
        WorkingDirectory       = $appWorkingDirPath
        RedirectStandardOutput = $true  # required to catch stdOut stream 
        RedirectStandardError  = $true  # required to catch stdErr stream 
        # RedirectStandardInput  = $true # only useful in some circumstances. Didn't find any use yet, but mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808663/get-live-output-from-process
        UseShellExecute        = $false # required to redirect streams
        CreateNoWindow         = $true  # does what is says (background work only)
    }

    $appProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]@{
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
        StartInfo           = $appProcessStartInfo
    }

    # to obtain available events of an object / type, read the event members of it:     "Get-Member -InputObject $appProcess -MemberType Event"
    $stdOutEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $appProcess -Action $eventScriptBlock -EventName 'OutputDataReceived' -MessageData $stdOutEventMessageData
    $stdErrEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $appProcess -Action $eventScriptBlock -EventName 'ErrorDataReceived' -MessageData $stdErrEventMessageData

    [void]$appProcess.Start()
    # async reading
    $appProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
    $appProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()

    while (!$appProcess.HasExited) {
        # Don't use method "WaitForExit()"! This will not show the output in real-time as it blocks the output stream!
        #   using "Sleep" from System.Threading.Thread for short sleep times below 1/1.5 seconds is better than 
        #   "Start-Sleep" in terms of PS overhead/performance (Test it yourself)
        [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(250)

        # maybe timeout ...
    }

} finally {
    if (!$appProcess.HasExited) {
        $appProcess.Kill() # WARNING: Entire process gets killed!
    }
    $appProcess.Dispose()

    if ($stdOutEvent -is [System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob]) {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $stdOutEvent.Name
    }
    if ($stdErrEvent -is [System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob]) {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $stdErrEvent.Name
    }
}
#------------------------------------------------------
#endregion
#######################################################


$stdOutText = $stdOutEventMessageData.Data.ToString() # final output for further usage
$stdErrText  = $stdErrEventMessageData.Data.ToString() # final errors for further usage
```

Comment: Do the above options assume the error is actually from powershell? I think that is the case

For me powershell will be running a command I usually run in command line (for a custom 3rd party application). 

When that command (lets call it command1) runs it will either return a 'success' message or 'fail' string. I want powershell to interpret that returning string and:

if 'success' run 'command2'
if 'fail' run 'command3'

Would i need to read the string into a variable and search that to determine whether to run command2 or command3?

Comment: That depends on the 3rd party application. If they are well programmed for command line operations, then they should return exit codes (`$LASTEXITCODE`) apart from their returned message.   E.g. Exit code `0` indicates success, everything from `1 upwards` indicates very often an error, but could also mean something special.   For exit codes you should use sample 2, for reading the success and error streams use 3 or 4. The error stream differs sometimes from exit codes, like "ping.exe". Ping returns exit code 1 if ping fails, but still writes everything to the success stream.

Comment: Best approach for sample 2 would be to combine exit codes with parsing the message returned by the 3rd party application.