# Buffering in redirected STDOUT for a child process

Tags: c#, process, io-redirection

Code like this can host a console app and listen to its output to STDOUT AND STDERR

```cs
      Process process = new Process();
      process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = context.WorkingDirectory;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; // if you don't and it reads, no more events
      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

      process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, dataReceivedEventArgs) =>
      {
        lastbeat = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data != null)
        {
          if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data.EndsWith("%"))
          {
            context.Logger.Information($"  PROGRESS: {dataReceivedEventArgs.Data}");
          }
          else
          {
            msg.Append(" STDERR (UNHANDLED EXCEPTION): ");
            msg.AppendLine(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
            success = false;
          }
        }
      };
      process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, dataReceivedEventArgs) =>
      {
        lastbeat = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data != null)
        {
          if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data.EndsWith("%"))
          {
            context.Logger.Information($" PROGRESS: {dataReceivedEventArgs.Data}");
          }
          else
          {
            context.Logger.Information($" STDOUT: {dataReceivedEventArgs.Data}");
          }
        }
      };

      lastbeat = DateTime.UtcNow;
      process.Start();
      process.BeginErrorReadLine();
      process.BeginOutputReadLine();
      // wait for the child process, kill it if hearbeats are too slow
      while (!process.HasExited)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        var elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - lastbeat;
        if (elapsed.TotalSeconds > heartbeatIntervalSeconds * 3)
        {
          success = false;
          msg.AppendLine("MODULE HEARTBEAT STOPPED, TERMINATING.");
          try
          {
            process.Kill(entireProcessTree: true); // ...and your children's children
          }
          catch (Exception ek)
          {
            msg.AppendLine(ek.Message);
          }
        }
      }

      if (success)
      {
        process.Dispose();
        context.Logger.Debug("MODULE COMPLETED");
        return JobStepResult.Success;
      }
      else
      {
        process.Dispose();
        context.Logger.Debug("MODULE ABORTED");
        throw new Exception(msg.ToString());
      }
```

The hosted processes are potentially very long running, so we invented a heartbeat mechanism. There's a convention here that STDERR is used for out of band communication so that STDOUT isn't polluted with heartbeat messages. Any line of text written to STDERR that ends with a percent sign is treated as a heartbeat, everything else is a normal error message.

We have two hosted modules, one of which works perfectly with heartbeats received in a timely manner, but the other seems to hang until all its output on both STDERR and STDOUT arrives in a flood.

The hosted modules are written in Lahey FORTRAN. I have no visibility on that code. I have suggested to the author that she may need to flush her output streams or possibly yield using whatever is the FORTRAN equivalent to `Thread.Sleep(10);`

However, it is not beyond the realms of possibility that the problem is on my side. When the modules are executed manually in a console their output appears at a steady pace with heartbeat messages appearing in a timely manner.

What governs the behaviour of captured streams?

- Are they buffered?
- Is there any way to influence this?

---

This may be related. [Get Live output from Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808663/get-live-output-from-process)

It seems (see comments) that this is an old problem. I pulled my hosting code out into a console app and the problem is manifest there too.

---

## Codiçil

This doesn't happen when the hosted console app is a dotnet core app. Presumably dotnet core apps use ConPTY because that way they can work the same across platforms.

Comment: This is an old problem, with old hacky workarounds. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection

Comment: Hmmm, maybe there is a new solution to this old problem https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I can't find anything on SO on this problem. I believe you are right. Why don't you write a short answer for me to accept? Just a few sentences explaining that redirection pipes are treated differently and you either have to fake a console or flush buffers in the source program, with the link for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem. An application can detect if they are running in a console and if not, choose to buffer their output. For example, this is something that the microsoft C runtime does deliberately whenever you call `printf`.

An application should not buffer writes to stderr, as errors should be made available before your program has a chance to crash and wipe any buffer. However, there's nothing to force that rule.

There are old solutions to this problem. By creating an off-screen console you can detect when output is written to the console buffer. There's a write up on [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection) that talks about this issue and solution in more detail.

More recently, Microsoft has modernised their console infrastructure. If you write to a modern console, your output is converted to a UTF-8 stream with embedded VT escape sequences. A standard that the rest of the world has been using for decades. For more details you can read their blog series on that work [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-backgrounder/).

I believe that it should be possible to build a new modern workaround. A stub process, similar to the Code Project link above, that uses these new [pseudo console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session) API's to launch a child process, capture console I/O and pipe that output unbuffered to its own stdio handles. I would be nice if such a stub process were distributed in windows, or by some other 3rd party, but I haven't found one yet.

There are a couple of samples available in [github.com/microsoft/terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/samples/ConPTY/EchoCon) that would be a good starting point if you wanted to create your own stub.

However I believe that using either this solution, or the old workaround would still merge the output and error streams together.

Comment: Do you mean a wholesale replacement for `System.Diagnostics.Process` and friends? Or a shim like RTconsole, but adapting legacy console apps to use ConPTY?

Comment: The Code Project link above includes a console process you can drop in which will; open an offscreen console, start a child process attached to that console, monitor the console buffer for writes, copy the bytes written to it's own stdout without buffering. A new shim console process could be written to create a pseudo console instead of the offscreen console, using the new api linked above. So you would start that console program from C#, and it will start your fortran program. The fortran program would not know it's output was redirected.

Comment: But if your fortran program buffers stderr, you're screwed. As you either have to merge stdout & stderr or deal with one of them being buffered.

Comment: Yeah I get it, I already pulled the source with that in mind. But it's in VC6 and I can't even load the project, and the boss is not pleased with the prospect of me having an interesting side project for which there is no direct paying customer. Luckily we have the source for the FORTRAN, we even have the original author. Adding flushes is possible.

Comment: Flushing from the child process is certainly the simplest solution.

Comment: @PeterWone Just FYI it's spelt Fortran, lowercase, and has been officially so spelt for over 30 years

Comment: @IanBush I know that but the last time I _wrote_ any was 35 years ago...